# Setting an array element with a sequence value error

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, normalization, array-broadcasting

Why do I get this error only for x_train? On commenting x_train out, no errors come.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-19-86f84f4d44b9> in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 x_train = np.array(x_train, dtype = np.float16) / 255
      2 x_val = np.array(x_val, dtype = np.float16) / 255.0
      3 x_test = np.array(x_test, dtype = np.float16) / 255.0
      4 x_train = x_train.reshape(-1, 224, 224, 3)
      5 x_val = x_val.reshape(-1, 224, 224, 3)

ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

Here is the relevant code I am running

```
def convert_image_to_array(image_dir):
  try:
    image = cv2.imread(image_dir)
    if image is not None:
      image = cv2.resize(image, (224,224))
      return img_to_array(image)
    else:
      return np.array([])
  except Exception as e:
    print(f"Error : {e}")
    return None

image_list_train, label_list_train = [], []

all_labels = [
    'Healthy Potato',
    'Potato early blight',
    'Rice neck blast',
    'Wheat leaf septoria',
    'Healthy Rice',
    'Potato late blight',
    'Tomato Early blight leaf',
    'Wheat leaf stripe rust',
    'Healthy Tomato',
    'Rice brown spot',
    'Tomato leaf late blight',
    'Healthy Wheat',
    'Rice leaf blast',
    'Wheat brown rust'
]

binary_labels = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13]

temp = -1

for directory in all_labels:
    plant_image_list = listdir(f"{dir_train}/{directory}")
    temp += 1
    for files in plant_image_list:
      image_path = f"{dir_train}/{directory}/{files}"
      image_list_train.append(convert_image_to_array(image_path))
      label_list_train.append(binary_labels[temp])

x_train, x_val, y_train, y_val = train_test_split(image_list_train, label_list_train, test_size = 0.2)

x_train = np.array(x_train, dtype = np.float16) / 255
x_val = np.array(x_val, dtype = np.float16) / 255.0
x_test = np.array(x_test, dtype = np.float16) / 255.0
x_train = x_train.reshape(-1, 224, 224, 3)
x_val = x_val.reshape(-1, 224, 224, 3)
x_test = x_test.reshape(-1, 224, 224, 3)
```

Additionally, I tried using dtype = object for all instead. Now different error comes during reshaping.
Code:

```
x_train = np.array(x_train, dtype = object) / 255
x_val = np.array(x_val, dtype = object) / 255.0
x_test = np.array(x_test, dtype = object) / 255.0
x_train = x_train.reshape(-1, 224, 224, 3)
x_val = x_val.reshape(-1, 224, 224, 3)
x_test = x_test.reshape(-1, 224, 224, 3)
```

Error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-20-3411c6f1375e> in <cell line: 4>()
      2 x_val = np.array(x_val, dtype = object) / 255.0
      3 x_test = np.array(x_test, dtype = object) / 255.0
----> 4 x_train = x_train.reshape(-1, 224, 224, 3)
      5 x_val = x_val.reshape(-1, 224, 224, 3)
      6 x_test = x_test.reshape(-1, 224, 224, 3)

ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 1374 into shape (224,224,3)
```

Again, for the rest, no problems occur as shown in the shapes:
Output:

```
x train shape: (1374,)
x val shape: (344, 224, 224, 3)
x test shape: (141, 224, 224, 3)
```

Comment: Examine `xtrain`.  Is it an array already?  dtype and shape?  or a list? length? What are elements like?  their shapes? dtypes. Some how you created a mix of objects that can't be turned into a numeric array.

Comment: Those `[]` results from the loader are probably giving you problems

Comment: @hpaulj x_train is a list with 1374 elements that are numpy arrays of the shape (224,224,3). dtype is float32. Even when trying x_train = np.array(x_train, dtype = np.float32) / 255.0, same error comes. The problem is I'm only facing the issue with x_train even though x_train and x_val have been split from the same list

Comment: If that is really true then `np.array(xtrain)` will work.  We can't examine xtrain for you!

Comment: That `array of size 1374` contains one or more arrays that differ in shape.  My guess is that one of your files cannot be loaded and you got None and put [] in the list.

Comment: Try `np.stack(x_train)`

Comment: i fixed the single array that differed in shape and removed it from x train and the corresponding label from y train, eventually fixed the problem by splitting using list slicing instead of train test split, dont know why.

Answer (score 0):

Found out that one of the elements didnt have a similar shape which was causing the problem.

I fixed the single array that differed in shape and removed it from x train and the corresponding label from y train. Still didnt fix the problem.

Eventually fixed the problem by splitting using list slicing instead of train test split, dont know why.

Comment: Not knowing what `train_test_split` does (or where it's from) we can't help you figure out what's happening.  What was different about bad array?  Often when loading images, a mix of color and b/w images gives this kind of problem.  On a newer `numpy` version, making your array from mixed shapes would give a "inhomogeneous' shape error message.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).